# How do I assign a MBP's Mission Control button (F3) for use in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro

I have a recent Mac Book Pro that I triple boot (OS X, Win7, BT5).  I'd like to use the Mission Control button (F3) in Windows 7 on my MBP to call [Dexpot's](http://dexpot.de/index.php?id=dexcontrol) "Windows Catalog."  Does anyone know of:

1) A setting in Windows (Registry adjustment, etc) that I could assign for this to work?

2) A setting in Dexpot that would configure this?

3) A piece of software that does this?

My preference for the answer is in the order above.  If I get multiple answers, the one that works, that is posted first, that does what 1) states, gets selected.  If 1) won't work, I'll select from answers to 2), etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a global hotkey for **{F3}** using AutoIt's [HotKeySet()](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm) and [Run()](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm) methods.